# How does zsh find commands?

Tags: catalina, path, zsh

Unless I switch back to bash, I now have to spell out the full path for scripts I have written.  How does zsh find commands?

Things in /bin, /use/bin, etc. still work, but things in ~/bin are “not found” even when that path is at the beginning of both $PATH and $path.

After putting

```
PATH="~/bin:$PATH
path="$PATH"
```

in ~/.zshrc,

```
echo $PATH; echo $path
```

shows it at the beginning of the path, but it still doesn't find the commands.  (And it's not permissions: the scripts work when I type their full paths.)

Comment: How did you check the contents of your PATH environment variable? (i.e. did you check from a zsh prompt? - etc)

Comment: What happens if you type- `typeset -U path` and then `path=(~/bin $path)` ? I would probably add this in the file `~/.zprofile`.

Comment: I typically use `$HOME/bin` instead of `~/bin` as it avoids  typically errors, like quoting `"~/bin`", which doesn't work while `"$HOME/bin"` does.

Comment: @user3439894, I'll try that.  ~/bin works in bash, though.  Apparently the claims of backwards compatibility for zsh are greatly exaggerated.

Comment: Can you add the result of the echo *and* copy/paste the full error message you get?

Comment: Quoting `~`, e.g. `echo "~"` in `bash` **will return** `~`! Not quoting it, e.g. `echo ~` will return e.g. `/Users/wgroleau` and the same holds true in `zsh`, so there is no backwards compatibility issue there.  Also, in your "After putting" you have `PATH="~/bin:$PATH` which is missing a closing quote, which it too causes an error.

Comment: Always use "$HOME". Never use "~". Regardless of your $SHELL. Also, I would declare your PATH in ~/.zshenv not ~/.zshrc but that's mostly just a personal preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zsh` doesn't expand `~` within quotes. You need to use

```
PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

instead.

PS: And `path=$PATH` is not required, `zsh` does this automatically

Comment: Well, either I left out the quotes or it did expand.  As I said, both variables _did_ start with ~/bin yet scripts there had to be spelled out fully.

Comment: @Wgroleau If the path variable contains ~ it will not work

Comment: @WGroleau Does your path start with "`~/bin`", or with "`/Users/yourname/bin`"? The first one *will not work*; the second should.

Comment: The first one will not work in zsh?  That's a step backward: it did work in bash.  But indeed, that silly limitation was the problem.  I like Apple, but I often get irritated at the constant changes in appearance and other things with no obvious benefit to justify the re-learning.

Comment: @WGroleau I think you're bit quick in judging there. You can't say that a jump from a 10 year old bash to a completely up to date zsh is "with no benefit". You'll get tonnes of features. Apple abandoned bash due to licensing issues (i.e. bash switched to GPLv3).

Comment: It's of no benefit to me (so far), and not the only change they've made that has seemed to be little more than eye candy or a treat for people who love to tinker.  I used to like it, and made a forty-year career out of it.  But at my age, now I'd rather just get the job done.

Comment: @WGroleau there is no need to move to `zsh` at all, you can easily stick to `bash` and upgrade to modern versions via Homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

You do not list how exactly you checked that the path is actually at the beginning of $PATH - but generally you should be aware that macOS Catalina changed the default shell from bash to zsh - and as such you'll need to move over any modifications you've made to PATH in .bashrc (for example) to the corresponding file for zsh (for example .zshrc, .zshenv or .zprofile).

The "standard" way of adding paths to macOS is to create a file at /etc/paths.d/ containing the path to the directory you want to add to the path. Then when you launch any shell, it should automatically be added to your PATH environment variable. For example create a file called:

```
/etc/paths.d/wgroleau
```

And make it contain just the following line of text:

```
/Users/wgroleau/bin
```

This would system wide change default paths to include that directory.

UPDATE: Following your comments I'm starting to think that your problem might not be PATH-related at all. You state that the problems you experience revolve around scripts that you have written yourself. If those scripts happens to be bash-scripts that start of with a shebang for bash, then those scripts needs to be converted to zsh to work if you haven’t got bash installed - or alternatively you could install bash again from HomeBrew or from Apple.

Comment: I am aware of that change in Catalina, hence the question.  I have edited to clarify that for reason unknown, your first suggestion doesn't work.  I will try the system suggestion; it's something I hadn't heard of.

Comment: @WGroleau Might be worth noting that changes to `/etc/paths.d` work system-wide, for all users/accounts

Comment: @nohillside Yes, that's already noted at the end of my answer. If you don't want it to be systemwide, use .zshrc or .zprofile in your home directory.

Comment: @WGroleau Checkout the update to my answer - could this be it?

Comment: Some of my scripts do specify bash.  So they should continue to work because they should execute in bash as always.  But the problem is not that they didn't work, but that zsh failed to find them in ~/bin, when ~/bin was the first item in the path.

Comment: @WGroleau Oh, okay - so you have installed bash... hmm, and they work when you start them manually with a full path. Have you tried using /Users/wgroleau/bin/ instead of ~/bin/ like I wrote in my answer?

Comment: No, I did not install bash.  Are you saying that Catalina removed it and Apple was wrong in telling me I'd have to run a command to stop using it?

Comment: **macOS Catalinia** has `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19)` **installed by default**, however it is no longer the default shell. It can still be used, if one so choose.

Comment: @WGroleau No, I just meant that you have it installed - i.e. the problem is not that the interpreter is missing. Again I must reiterate I think you should try using /Users/wgroleau/bin instead of ~/bin, as your problem seems to be the lack of expansion of that.